# why the variable data suddenly changed to item

Tags: android, react-native

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <SectionList
    sections={[
      { title: 'D', data: ['Devin'] },
      {
        title: 'J',
        data: ['Jackson', 'James', 'Jillian', 'Jimmy', 'Joel', 'John', 'Julie'],
      },
    ]}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
      <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  />
</View>;
```

Can you tell me why the variable `data` suddenly changed to `item`, I've no idea what happened here.

Comment: Neither Do I .. Your question is not clear enough . Please read [ask] and Edit your question with proper details .

Comment: @ridwan syarifudin please tell me your doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying tell that why data name under your **sections** has changed to item in renderItem right?

SectionList will work as `for loop` where it will take your data from

```
{[
  { title: 'D', data: ['Devin'] },
  { title: 'J', data: ['Jackson', 'James', 'Jillian', 'Jimmy', 'Joel', 'John', 'Julie'] }
]}
```

and return one by one as item. You can change **item** to **data** also, it is just a variable.

Hope you got answer.